# PostgreSQL function returns "query has no destination for result data"

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I wrote this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION select_all_sessions(rettype anyelement, dbname varchar(30))
RETURNS SETOF anyelement AS $$
        DECLARE
                sess VARCHAR;
        BEGIN
                FOR sess IN SELECT session
                            FROM dblist
                LOOP
                    IF EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM pg_database
                                WHERE datname = sess) THEN
                        SELECT dblink_connect('dblinktest' || sess, 'host=localhost port=5432 dbname=' || sess || ' user=postgres password=password');
                        SELECT *
                        FROM dblink('dblinktest'||sess,
                        'SELECT * FROM ' || dbname || ';');
                    END IF;
                END LOOP;
        END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This is meant to be run on a server where there are several databases with the same tables inside. The table dblist contains all the databases that existed on the server, but some of them might not exist anymore so I have to check if it before using dblink. The goal is to query a table across all the databases at once.
The create function query works, but when I try to use the function it says "query has no destination for result data.". 
I am new in the PL/PGSQL world, please help :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+query+has+no+destination+for+result+data

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `dblink_connect()` with out a `SELECT`. And add the result of a query to the returned result use `RETURN QUERY` and a final `RETURN` at the end (see ["40.6.1.2. `RETURN NEXT` and `RETURN QUERY`"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/plpgsql-control-structures.html#AEN61180)).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION select_all_sessions(rettype anyelement, dbname varchar(30))
RETURNS SETOF anyelement AS $$
        DECLARE
                sess VARCHAR;
        BEGIN
                FOR sess IN SELECT session
                            FROM dblist
                LOOP
                    IF EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM pg_database
                                WHERE datname = sess) THEN
                        dblink_connect('dblinktest' || sess, 'host=localhost port=5432 dbname=' || sess || ' user=postgres password=password');
                        RETURN QUERY SELECT *
                        FROM dblink('dblinktest'||sess,
                        'SELECT * FROM ' || dbname || ';');
                    END IF;
                END LOOP;
                RETURN;
        END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```